# Recent posts on homepage

Tags: homepage, recent-posts

I have made a page where you people can find al the teasers (teaser made with the read more tag) from my posts.( By clicking one of them you "open" the whole article, including photo's, ... . This is working well.
On my homepage I want a short welcome text and in a sidebar my 3 recent posts. 
I'm first trying to get the recent posts on my homepage with following code

```
<?php
function recentPosts() {
    $rPosts = new WP_Query();
    $rPosts->query('showposts=3');
        while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post(); ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('recent-thumbnails'); ?></a>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```

This is working well but on my homepage I'm getting all the content from my articles and I only want a teaser. (2 lines for example). 
I don't know how to do this here. Below you see the code of the home page.

```
<?php
/**
 * @content not visible
 * @content not visible
 *
 * Template Name: homepage
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php echo recentPosts(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: How do you want this "welcome text" to be added? I assume, via the post content for the page assigned as `page_for_posts`?

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure that your template file is named `home.php`.

Second, there's no need to use a custom query loop in this context. If you only want to display 3 posts on the blog posts index (i.e. the "homepage"), then filter the main loop query via `pre_get_posts`:

```
function wpse83660_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '3' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse83660_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

And you can replace your entire `recentPosts()` function with a normal loop.

Thurd, you're calling `the_content()` both outside of a loop instantiation, and expecting it to return content other than what it will return:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This call to `get_content()` has 2 problems:

1. You haven't instantiated a loop:

   ```
   if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   ```
2. In the *blog posts index* context, this call to `the_content()` will return the content of the *posts in the blog posts index*, **not** the content of the *page assigned as `page_for_posts`

By solving the second problem, we'll fix the first as well.

To get at the post_content for the page assigned as `page_for_posts`, use [`get_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page), and pass it `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )`:

```
$page_object = get_page( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
```

Then, output its results:

```
if ( ! is_null( $page_object ) ) {
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page_object->post_content );
}
```

So, your entire template file will look like so:

```
/**
 * Blog posts index template file
 *
 * Displays the blog posts index
 * 
 * @filename: home.php
 */

get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('recent-thumbnails'); ?></a>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

endwhile; endif;

$page_object = get_page( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
if ( ! is_null( $page_object ) ) {
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page_object->post_content );
}

get_footer();
```

Comment: Bennet, When you want to retrieve the content from a page you don't use the_content() ? The_content() is only used for content from blogposts? Is this right?

Comment: I have entered the following code into my template file but nothing happened. There is no content in it...

Comment: Let's back up a bit: I'm assuming that you're using a **static front page**, and that you're displaying your blog posts index on a **separate static page**? Is this assumption incorrect?

Comment: Under settings, reading, I have a static frontpage and I also assigned a **static page to display the blogposts**. (I first create a blank page, and then assigned this page to display blog posts)

Comment: Okay, so, in that case, for the static page you've assigned to display blog posts, *you can't access post_content via `the_content()`*, because that page is considered a special/system page. That's why you have to query that page separately, and output post_content directly from the returned object. You *could* call `setup_postdata()`, but that adds a couple of unnecessary steps, both to `setup_postdata()`, and then to `wp_reset_postdata()` afterward.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about but I've got a working blog posts index page. I receive the content on the blog post index with the get_content() function and this is working. Only on my index page this will not work I assume because when I type get_content() it will load page content and i need post content. Is this right or am i completely wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by **index page**? Are you talking about your **site front page**?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7312/discussion-between-niels-jansen-and-chip-bennett)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is calling the `the_content()` function, which returns the whole post.

If all you want is a "teaser" then your code should call `the_excerpt()` function

Answer (score 0):

Add `<?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>` right after/below `while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post(); ?>` and you should get your "More" tags working.